# Setting size to custom iOS font doesnt work

Tags: objective-c, ios, font-size

I am using some custom fonts in my iphone app. They are displayed correctly, but i cant change their size.

Here is how set this font for UILabel:

```
myLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cabin-Regular" size:18];
```

This label is part of uitableview cell, if that could play any role.

Label settings in IB:

[image]

I change only color, text and font in code for this label.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Is the label's `adjustsFontSizeToWidth` property set to `YES`?  Is the label big enough to display its entire contents with that font at that size?

Comment: I updated question with more data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the font is loaded correctly?

You can try:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", familyName);
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"\t%@",fontName);
    }
}
```

This will show you all the fonts that are loaded. Make sure the same name "Cabin-Regular" is showing up exactly the same. A lot of times the font itself isn't loaded and then the font-size won't be used at all.

Comment: I tried your code and my Cabin font is not printed. But i have it in plist correctly spelled (the same as ttf filename).

Comment: To add add a font to you project see the answer of arthan.v or try this http://refactr.com/blog/2012/09/ios-tips-custom-fonts/ (the same but with nice screenshots)

Comment: Your link in comments solved the problem. I had to click on my font in Xcode and check "Target membership".

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your font in your `Xcode`, if you are adding manually.

1. Add your font in your project files
2. Go to your `Project name-Info.plist` file, right click and click `Add Row`.
3. In your new row type `Fonts provided by application`. If you expand it you can add new items, in there add value to `item 0` . The value should be your `font` file name. like below image

[image]

4. Double click on your  font, it'll open in external editor, like following image

[image]

5.Give that name into your `fontWithName:` method. If you are setting value to your `tableviewcell`. the code will be
`cell.nameLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cabin" size:18.0];`

It works fine for me. I hope it helps :)