# how to modify the font size of label

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

I creat a button set the background image.then add a label to the button,I try to modify the size of font in label but failed.I don't know how to solve this ,anyone help me please.

this is my code:

```
returnButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    returnButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 9, 50, 28);

    [returnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [returnButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"US MEAT_buttons.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [returnButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 2, 50, 20)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeiti-Medium.ttc" size:10];
    label.text = @"返回";//返回means "return"
    [returnButton addSubview:label];
    [label release];
```

Comment: so your font STHeiti-Medium.ttc is not loaded ?

Comment: You have to install the font and add it in plist in Supported Fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your custom font has not been added properly:

1. Add the font files to your resource files
2. Edit your Info.plist: Add a new entry with the key Fonts provided by application.
3. For each of your files, add the file name to this array

   `label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeiti-Medium" size:10];`

Please check the following answer [How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom fonts, that has to be in resources folder, and you need to add that `font` details into `plist` file. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798002/setting-size-to-custom-ios-font-doesnt-work/13800169#13800169)