# How to use custom fonts in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.2

I Want to implement custom font in my app. So i have added that in my Project Source code. I don't want to set that programatically. Is this possible that I can do this with setting  properties in xib?

Comment: No, this can be done only one runtime, you need to set in your code programmatically only..

Comment: [see this link , might help you]
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-custom-font-in-xcode.html

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798002/setting-size-to-custom-ios-font-doesnt-work#answer-13800169)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

1. **Add** your custom font into your project , i.e. Dragged the font file(`CALIBRIZ_0.TTF`) into XCode project.
2. **Edit Info.plist**: Add a new entry with the key "Fonts provided by
   application".
3. For each of your files, add the file name to this array

   [image]
4. Opened the font in font book(**double click on your font in finder**) to see what the real filename is and
   I see this:

[image]

**Now set font to your label**

```
yourLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:15];
```

Follow [this](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-use-custom-font-in-iphone-sdk.html) to get more

Comment: Nice!! its work for me.

Comment: Make sure the fonts are in your Copy Bundle Resources. Other wise it won't work!

Comment: Also make sure to use the System Name of the Font, not the name of the file

Comment: Also make sure you use the name of the font NOT the name of the file.

Answer (score 24):

I think you had not searched well.

> ```
> How to add CUSTOM fonts:-
> Steps:-
>   1.  Add your custom font files into your project using XCode as a resource
>   2.  Add a key to your info.plist file called "Fonts provided by application".
>   3.  Make this key an array
>   4.  For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to theUIAppFonts array
>   5.  Save info.plist
>   6.  Now call UIFont *fontCustom = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:12];  to get the custom fonts.
> ```

**NOTE:-** Make sure the fonts are in your Copy Bundle Resources.

For example:- If you want to use "`Nexa Light`" font in your app, then add "Nexa Light.otf" into your project and call in this way.

```
UIFont *fontCustom = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Nexa Light" size:14];
lblName.font = fontCustom;
```

Comment: adding every font file to Target is also an important task.

Answer (score 11):

**Step 1:**
Copy the font file to your resource files. Make sure it is added to Copy Bundle Resources in your Build Phases settings.

**Step 2:**
In your Info.plist just configure this like below this screen

[image]

**Step 3:**

Access and use it with the following code:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_FONT" size:10];
```

Comment: Following code is for To Know exact font name after being install in system.
let fontFamilies = UIFont.familyNames
  for fontFamily in fontFamilies {
   let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName:fontFamily)
   print("\(fontFamily)  \(fontNames)")
  }

Answer (score 11):

Use font name from **.ttf** file

and you can also find from this [link](http://iosfonts.com/)

after add this font name with it's extension like **(OpenScan.ttf)** in to `.plist` file

[image]

After add this font to **.plist** file, you can use it by

```
[self.txtField setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:13]];
```

And for more information read my Answer [Adding custom fonts to iOS app finding their real names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names/15985113#15985113).