# NSMutableAttributedString crashing with custom font

Tags: ios, swift, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring

This is strange.

This works:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 14)
```

This works:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:
    UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 18)!,
    range: ((attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Forgot your password? Reset it here")))
```

This doesn't. Gives a crash:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:
    UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 18)!,
    range: ((attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Email or password are incorrect."))).
```

First example shows that OpenSans-Regular works fine in the app. (Same font used in 3rd example).

Second example shows attributed string works fine with custom font.

Third example shows attributed string with custom font doesn't work.

I double checked, OpenSans-Regular I correctly copied in my project :

**Project directory :**

[image].

**Copy bundle resources :**

[image]

**Info.plist :**

[image].

Comment: this `UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 18)` is probably `nil` due to either the custom-font's name is not correct or the custom font is not supported by the app.

Comment: Ensure availability of valid font by executing code with `if-let` and see what result you get

Comment: FYI - the name you pass as the name to `UIFont(name:size:)` is often different than the base name of the ttf file.

Comment: What is the postscript name of that font? Also it's not NSMutableAttributedString that make it crash, it's your font, because you used a `!` saying "Crash if nil" while you didn't on setting the font in your label (which I expect didn't work).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021945/ios-ttf-fonts-only-partially-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413332/uifont-woes-some-custom-fonts-loading-but-others-are-not

Comment: read https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/ and there make sure that you are using correct name of the font (see point 5 in that article)

Comment: @maddy : It turns out your words are 100% correct. It should be used as OpenSans instead of OpenSans-Regular as per the link suggests. Please post your answer for future reference.

Comment: @maddy : I however suspect the question is not duplicate. They are related but definitely not duplicate.

Comment: @Nitish No, the answer says to use `OpenSans` because it's the postscript name of the font (read the answer, use FontBook.app on your Mac), what I suggested too. And that's clearly the same solution because of the same reason of why using "OpenSans". Then it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply did not correctly add the font with name `"OpenSans-Regular"`,

First line, line:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 14)
```

works, because `titleLabel.font` is optional, thus it has no problem with `UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 14)` being evaluated to nil. So it does not prove that `"OpenSans-Regular"` was added correctly.

However, in the third example:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:
    UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 18)!,
    range: ((attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Email or password are incorrect.")))
```

here you are force unwrapping it (notice `!` at the end of `UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 18)!`), thus it crashes - this on the other hand proves you did not add it correctly.

**EDIT**

Make sure you add `"OpenSans-Regular"` correctly to the project. I recommend going over the list at this [blog entry](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/), especially check point number 5 there (names).

**EDIT 2**

As @rmaddy pointed out, `"OpenSans-Regular"` is `"OpenSans"` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021945/ios-ttf-fonts-only-partially-work). Therefore rather use:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
```

And:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:
    UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 18)!,
    range: ((attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Email or password are incorrect.")))
```

Comment: I double check my project. Font is correctly copied. Please check my updated question.

Comment: try this: `titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 14)!` - if that crashes, there is a problem in adding the font..

Comment: Turns out maddy's observation is correct. And yours as well. Thanks Milan.

Comment: @Nitish no problem

Comment: Accepting you answer since Maddy isn't posting his.

Answer (score 3):

This will avoid app crash. Force unwrapping of UIFont may be reason for app crash. Try this and see.

```
if let openSansRegularFont18 = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 18) {
   attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:
    openSansRegularFont18,
    range: ((attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Email or password are incorrect.")))
} else {
  print("OpenSans-Regular is nil (not installed/added in your project)")
  // Font file name differs from the actual font name.  Use font name as "OpenSans" only.
}
```

Comment: else is getting called. I wonder why is that since I added the font correctly.

Comment: Can you share font (family) files or source of font files. I can check it with my project

Comment: @Nitish You've added the font correctly but you are using the wrong name. See the links I just posted under the question.

Comment: @Nitish - Link shared by rmaddy may solve your problem. It states remove word `regular`. Just use `OpenSans` only.

Comment: Turns out Maddy is correct. Thanks Krunal for your inputs.