# programmatically set UILabel font to User Defined Runtime Attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have an `UIViewController` in which I create an `UILabel` programmatically in its' `viewDidLoad:` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UILabel  *navTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 0, 100, 100)];

    navTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    navTitleLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#000029"];

    [navTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Pennyscript" size:20]];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleLabel;
}
```

I have the "User defined Runtime Attribute" set in the `ViewController's` identity inspector tab:

[image]

What I'm trying to do here is programmatically set the `UILabel` **navTitleLabel**'s font to my custom font, then add that `UILabel` into the `navigationBar's` `titleView`. What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish this goal?

With the UDKA(*User defined key attribute*) in the VC ID-inspector, the app crashes with this stack trace message:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fontName.'*

When I remove my *User Defined Key Attribute* from the ViewController, I can then navigate to the VC with no crash.

Comment: Did you add the font to your project in the _Info Plist_ file? And the corresponding _.ttf_-files?

Comment: Yes. I did that already. I have already used the font on UILabels in the storyboard.. but this UILabel is programmatic so I am confused.

Comment: hmm, usually you wouldn't have to define the _User defined attribute_ then either... it should be sufficient to use the font in code just as you do.

Comment: are you sure _Pennyscript_ is the correct name of the font? you can check the proper font names of the custom font using the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names

Comment: the _user define runtime attribute_ and the line `[navTitleLabel setValue:@"NavBar Title" forKeyPath:@"fontName"]` are superfluous, just setting the font of the label is enough by the way.

Comment: Yes I know how to print the fonts, it is in there, and is most definitely "Pennyscript", I have already used the font on several `UILabels` and `UIButtons`, my program is crashing when loading the VC that I'm trying to use it in, I think the problem is that the *User defined Key Attribute* is in the VC's id-inspector rather than in the UILabel's id-inspector, and oh.. I didn't know that, I was just trying to get it to work

Comment: why are you using _user define attributes at all_? can't just you remove that line? what's its purpose here?

Comment: It's the only way to actually recognize the .otf file from the .plist file. It doesn't work without the *User Defined Runtime Attribute* being declared.

Comment: hmm, that's strange. i am using custom fonts in my apps and i never had to do this to recognize any font. are you doing this in all the views where you use the font?

Comment: Yes I am using it in all of the views, but only in the identity inspector of the UILabel's and UIButton's that I need the font for.

Comment: i still dont get what this line does: `[navTitleLabel setValue:@"NavBar Title" forKeyPath:@"fontName"]`. why are you setting tthe label's `fontName` property to **NavBar Title**

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest I was just trying to get the font to work lol.

Comment: remove the line `[navTitleLabel setValue:@"NavBar Title" forKeyPath:@"fontName"]`, it doesn't make any sense and it causes your crash! you also don't need user define runtime attributes!

Answer (score 2):

In your View Controller define a property as:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myFontName;
```

And in the view controllers Identity inspector change the Keypath from `fontName` to `myFontName`.

And change this code:

```
[navTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Pennyscript" size:20]];
```

to:

```
[navTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:myFontName size:20]];
```

Tutorials:

1. [Reference](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/30/xcode-runtime-attributes/)
2. [Reference](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/user-defined-runtime-attributes/)
3. [Reference](http://samdods.github.io/blog/2014/04/08/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-interface-builder/)
4. [Reference](http://blog.gaeremynck.com/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

The exception that you get is because you try to set a **property** (this is what `setValue:forKeypath:` is doing) of `UILabel`. Since you pass the string **fontName** as keypath, iOS attempts to set the property `fontName` of `UILabel` to the value **NavBar Title**. This is why  you are getting the exception, because `UILabel` doesn't have a property called `fontName`! Calling `[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Pennyscript" size:20]];` should be enough!

Comment: Sorry this isn't right... I removed the "*User Defined Key Attribute*" and that fixed the crash... I will update code., it is still not working though.. I must give the UILabel the UDKA somehow.. but programmatically.

Comment: Believe me, **setting custom fonts has nothing to do with user defined runtime attributes**! Check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: does it work when you just set the system font in a smaller size? are the changes taken? you need to take small steps and start debugging your issue further., try e.g.: `[navTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];`. does this work and your font is getting smaller? if not you know that your issue is not because of the font, but because the label is not set properly.

Comment: Oh wow... sadd, the problem is that I was never setting the UILabel's text.. haha. It's totally working... with no need of the User Defined Key Attribute

Comment: what happens when you print out the font of the `navTitleLabel ` with `NSLog(@"Font: %@", navTitleLabel.font);` after you set the font with `[navTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Pennyscript" size:20]];`, does it actually tell you that the font has been set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Copy font in project File. add in project then add in info.plist

[image]

then put this methods

> UILabel  *navTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]
>   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17, 0, 100, 100)];
>
> ```
> navTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
> navTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
> navTitleLabel.text = @"hello";
>  navTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pennyscript" size:navTitleLabel.font.pointSize];
> self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleLabel;
> ```