# Strange "Crash" with Font added to Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, xcode6

I've added a custom font TTF file to an app I'm making.

[image: Project Bundle]

I've also added the `UIAppFonts` key to the plist, as required.

[image: Project Plist]

Now, when I launch the app, it hits the "app is crashing in AppDelegate" breakpoint we all know so well.

[image: App "Crashing"]

I can't figure out a way to inspect the exception, but what's stranger is that if I play it through, the app continues just fine -- even allows me to debug. On top of that, the font in question is actually loaded, so there doesn't seem to be any issue there either. Not sure where to start looking for this one.

Comment: Please remove the white spaces from the font file name. And change name in info.plist file.

Comment: The font has a space in it, is there a reason that the space would break something?

Comment: Weird. Sometimes there's non-crashing exceptions you can "play through" (especially in Cocoa Desktop, but I've also seen C++ exceptions in in iOS Core Audio). But an exception that breaks in UIApplicationMain -like your screenshot- usually tends to be (in my experience) a 'zombie' (i.e., message sent to deallocated instance), and those always crash. I may be wrong... Did you enable an exception breakpoint? Or NSZombie? (if you don't know how, google those two).

Comment: Can you try once by removing spaces from file name and as well as from plist?

Comment: @NicolasMiari, yes I've added the exception breakpoint. Haven't tried Zombies yet.

Comment: @PradhyumanSinhChavda, I'm trying this now, but could you expand on *why* this might be an issue, or point to some documentation?

Comment: @PradhyumanSinhChavda Removing the space did not have any effect.

Comment: Does the log say anything?

Comment: Did you try with another font file, and did it work then?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi check NSGOD's answer on this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names

Comment: Ok, so it's somewhat related to the space issue -- and it's completely clear if you look at my screenshots. The file name was Sports World Regular, and I put Sports World Light in the Info.plist.

Comment: ya you used different name in your plist.

Comment: ... Yep, that's what I said. Since you've moved me in the right direction, would you like to write this up as an answer, or would you rather I do it myself?

Comment: ok i will write at as an answer.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi you can edit my answer if you want to add further info in it.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi Hello... yes i saw moderates rejected your update. I didn't do anything. Try to update once again. IF they reject it again then can you pls provide your answer and i will edit it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the white spaces from the font file name. And change name in info.plist file.
And Use the same font name which in in the .ttf file. For more information you can check [NSGOD's Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names)

Comment: Hey, I tried editing your comment, and it appears that my changes were lost. Did you reject the edit?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi Hello... yes i saw moderates rejected your update. I didn't do anything. Try to update once again. IF they reject it again then can you pls provide your answer and i will edit it here.

Answer (score 5):

The font file is probably not added to the target.

[image]

Comment: Hey there Oleksii, not sure if you saw the discussion in comments, but the issue wasn't the font not being included, but that I was pointing at the wrong font name (Light vs Regular).

Comment: Thanks much! That was the only issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a symbolic breakpoint set for "objc_exception_throw"?  It will break on all exceptions, including the ones that will be caught by some code's try/catch frame.

Since you are seeing it show the break at UIApplicationMain,  it is likely this is the closest source code to the problem.  Check the stack frames in the left column to see if there are Apple internal methods being called.

Change the slider at the bottom of the left column in Xcode to show more of the stack frames if some are hidden.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned in the comments above, I had the exception breakpoint set on the project, but it was not catching anything. There wasn't a meaningful stack, as best as I could tell, since it was just within the app main, as you indicated. I'm not sure about showing "more," haven't seen or tried that before. Perhaps tonight I'll play with that again.