# What's the narrowest font in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts

I am trying to find the narrowest font, that I can use in iOS. Screen space is limited and I want something I can use in 11 pts size still keeping 8 characters on the line. Is the Apple Watch font available for iPhone?

Comment: Here is a website with all fonts available: http://iosfonts.com

Comment: You can install your own custom font and use whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a script to check:

```
import UIKit

let allFontFamilies = UIFont.familyNames() as [String]
var allFontNames: [String] = []
for family in allFontFamilies {
    allFontNames += UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family) as [String]
}

let string = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
var minimum: (width: CGFloat, font: String) = (width: CGFloat.max, font: "")
for fontName in allFontNames {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = string
    label.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 11)
    let size = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: CGFloat.max))
    if size.width < minimum.width {
        minimum = (width: size.width, font: fontName)
    }
}

minimum.width
minimum.font
```

Which outputs:

`PartyLetPlain`

Not sure about text spacing for a specific word., but you could replace the string with your own and drop this in a playground to see.

Answer (score 0):

Either try [IOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com/)

or

Check the [official site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202771). There is a list included with fonts, that can be downloaded from apps if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Watchkit's font `SanFrancisco` not available in the system fonts but you can import to your project.

In order to do that

1. You need to download font and other sources from [here](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/)
2. Than import `TTF` files to your project add `Fonts provided by application` parameter with font names to your plist file [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15985113/2103088) could has better explanation.