# SF UI Text-Light(New san francisco) font doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, uilabel

I am try to change font for a label but it's doesn't work font name:new New san francisco.

Import that font into project and add in info.plist and this is my code

```
labelname.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SF UI Text-Light" size:12];
```

If I use that's work fine

```
labelname.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
```

But New san francisco font doesn't work. I don't know what I miss :(

[image]

Comment: check your build phases, make sure these fonts are in the "Copy bundle resources" tab, and try `[UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Light"]`, eliminate the spaces between them.

Comment: `SF UI Text-Light` is its font family, and font name is `.SFUIText-Light`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's happens because you use the wrong System name for the font. Try to use

```
labelname.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Light" size:12];
```

How to find System font names see here
[Adding custom fonts to iOS app finding their real names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names)

Answer (score 5):

I try to log the system font and find the font name is ".SFUIText-Light" ,so

```
labelname.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFUIText-Light" size:12];
```

this is work.

Answer (score 4):

Please use https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyw7kl0mtrftjix/San-Francisco-UI-and-COMPACT.zip?dl=0 this link and download the .ttf instead of .otf file. i am sure you got the result, best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an update: you should be using the system font APIs in UIFont. For example:

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
```

Apple specifically tells developers to no longer rely on a font name or file system representation for the system font.

As an aside, I made up a library for using many of the special features of the SF font in your app. Feel free to check it out:
https://github.com/djfitz/SFFontFeatures

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT, really.

Use this code, it is very, very useful. With it you can know the real name of the font.

```
let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames

for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")

    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
    print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
}
```

I show you an example.

The Font file (you must add it into your project, as any other file):

[image: Screenshot 1: Font file]

The Font file name in "Info.plist" (exactly the same name with the file extension):

[image: Screenshot 2: Info plist]

Finally, the output in the log Debug (created by the code)

[image: Screenshot 3: Debug output]

So, you can write this font name:

```
headerLabel.font = UIFont(name:"SFProDisplay-Heavy", size:30)
```

Use this code. It has saved me time. It is very useful (I think)!