# What is required in order to access a font held by a cocoapod?

Tags: swift, fonts, cocoapods, assets

So I created a `cocoa-pod` and successfully added a font to it.  When I run `pod install` in the consuming project, it pulls in the fonts.  I'm even able to use the fonts in the storyboard.  However when I try to access the font either directly in the consuming project or in the pod via `UIFont(name: "my-fonts-name", size: 20)!` the font initializer returns nil.

The font is `".ttf"` file extension.

**I have done the following:**

- The font is in my pod's file structure and finder structure.
- My font has its pod listed as a target member.
- My fonts are in build phases -> Bundle Resources.
- My font name/s are in my plist.

I also tried running:

```
    UIFont.familyNames.forEach({ familyName in
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print(familyName, fontNames)
    })
```

and nothing resembling my custom font was not printed.

I am then getting `"The file “PPUIElementModules91.framework” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."` I don't have permission to access the very pod I created. I have gone through all the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924809/the-file-myapp-app-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission-to-vi) one by one but none worked.

Comment: The font name and the name of the ttf file are rarely the same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names and look at the last couple of answers for Swift code.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy, I have already tried printing out all the available fonts and my font is not listed...-Even though it IS available in the storyboard of the pod consuming project.  Will update my question.

Comment: To clarify, nothing resembling my custom font's name was listed either.