# Replicating iOS7's navigation bar's title text

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Under iOS 7 I'd like to replace the title text view in a navigation bar by a custom view that includes another text view that looks identical to the default one. (Essentially, I need to add another view to the title element, but to do that I have to replace the whole thing).

How can I create a UILabel that's guaranteed to look the same as the default (same font, size, etc?)

In other words - how can I programmatically find the font face and size used by the OS for the title view of a navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 100, 40)];
[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
[titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[titleLabel setText:@"Rajneesh071"];
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:titleLabel];
```

If you want to use your own font then you can use this.

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:14]
```

You can get font name using this.This will print `HelveticaNeueInterface-M3`

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14].fontName);
```

And size

```
NSLog(@"%f",[UIFont systemFontSize]);
```

Follow this answer [How to use custom fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk/14377069#14377069)

Comment: Without setting a font, that display's nothing at all. The crux of my problem is to work out how to use the same font as iOS would have done. I'm currently doing this: titleLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]. That seems to work, but there's no guaranty

Comment: systemFontOfSize: this will solve your problem, check edited answer

Comment: That won't guarantee it. What happens if apple change the size slightly in an update...

Comment: how can he update size, you are specifying size.. check ans again

Comment: I want the size to be the same the the OS would have used had I not replaced the view. Fixing the size to 14 point may be the same as iOS 7.02 would have used, but it may not be the same as 7.03 uses...

Comment: NSLog(@"%f",[UIFont systemFontSize]);

Comment: That's the system font size. It isn't necessarily the size that the OS will use for the title text!