# My fontSize doesn't work with my custom font

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, font-size, uifont

I import my fonts in my project

[image]

I create a class style.swift

```
struct Style {


    //fonts
    static var GothamBlackItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-BlackItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamBold = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Bold.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamBoldItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-BoldItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamBook = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Book.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamBookItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-BookItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamLight = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Light.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamLightItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-LightItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamMedium = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Medium.ttf", size: 4)
    static var GothamMediumItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-MediumItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamThin = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Thin.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamThinItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-ThinItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamUltra = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Ultra.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamUltraItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-UltraItalic.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamExtraLight = UIFont(name: "Gotham-XLight.ttf", size: 12)
    static var GothamExtraLightItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham-XLightItalic.ttf", size: 12)

}
```

In my view controller, i call the font GothamMedium in my Label :

```
myLabel.font=Style.GothamMedium
```

The font is correct **but the fontsize is not working.**
Can you tell me how can I change the font size ?

Comment: Not working how? What settings on the label? Have you debugged to check the label settings at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is difference between `font name` and `font file name`, you've mentioned `font file name`, not `font name`. Double click the font, it'll open in `Font Book`, title is the `font name` now the `font` should be created as

```
static var GothamBlackItalic = UIFont(name: "Gotham Black", size: 12)
```

[image: Font Name]

Also add `Fonts provided by application` in your `plist`. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377069/1866077)