# Add Malayalam font in iOS system directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uifont

I want to display HTML with the Malayalam font in my webview. If I install that font in my mac and load it in any browser, I can see the text in that font. Can I install a font on an iOS device and load HTML with that font in my webview?

Comment: Do you want to deliver this font as part of a web site or an app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk  . Link may help u....!!!

Comment: @sschale: For app only

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the font as part of your bundle resources and then specify the font name in the Info.plist file under `Fonts provided by application` property.

Comment: These all I tried already. plist is not helping... But it is possible if we add its location in css

Comment: Can you point me to the font location where you got the malayalam font and some sample text that you put in the iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load custom Fonts with a local CSS with the following steps

1. Add your Font to the App...make sure that the file is targeted properly to the Application
2. Then add your Font to your App-Info.plist
3. Run the following code to check which name the font/fontfamily has for the System.

   > NSLog(@"Available fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
4. Copy that name and use them in your CSS as follows...@font-face is not needed

   body {
      font-family:"Liberation Serif"; 
       }