# Cannot display amharic alphabets in the detail text on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display amharic alphabets in the detail text on a UITableViewCell but it shows the question marks instead. Can any one help me regarding this issue?

[image]

Comment: can you show some code that you attempted

Comment: var dictionary = [
        "A Fleet Of" : "እናት",
        "Abbey" : "ያልሆነ",
] if (self.resultSearchController.active)
        {
            cell!.textLabel?.text = self.filteredEnglishWords[indexPath.row] // "\u{1203}"
            cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.dictionary[self.englishWords[indexPath.row]]
            return cell!}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font of label do not support displaying Amharic.

You can download other font like Kefa in [here](http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/temp/4902269f7e30501514593fc0f0a88993_20160529/4902269f7e30501514593fc0f0a88993/OnlineWebFonts_COM_4902269f7e30501514593fc0f0a88993.zip) and drag "Kefa-Regular.ttf" into your project.

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk) to setup.

Hope it helps   :)