# set font not working in cell.label in UItableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel

I had an application, in which I'm setting a label in custom cell according to the content. I do that with this code:

```
if(condition)
{ 
  [cell.dtlsnameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri-Bold" size:12]];
}
else
{
  [cell.dtlsnameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:12]];
}
[cell.dtlsnameLabel setText:@“dghgshdg”];
```

But it is not working correctly. Can anybody point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: which condition pass you in if statement ?

Comment: What does "going wrong" mean? Is the text set correctly?

Comment: you are add font file calibri-bold and calibri?

Comment: Your app is crashing because Calibri and Calibri-Bold font is not available in ios by default. you have to add this fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Please read below link contain then some idea got it:

http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/how-to-custom-font-on-springboard.97478/

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because Calibri and Calibri-Bold font is not available in iOS by default. You have to add this fonts. To know, how to add custom font in your app: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14377069/3976183)