# getting string value from plist in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have been working on tHe plist in iOS.I have saved font style **Marker Felt Thin 25.0** as string in plist.

Now i want to retrieve that string and assign font to the my tableview cell text.

while i am trying is not affecting the cell why is it so...?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[[dict objectForKey:@"Font"]size:15]];
```

How can i do it...?

here is the plist screenshot
[image]

PList[2423:126298] {
    Names =     (
        Ajith,
        Bhuvan,
        Carrie,
        David,
        Ezzel,
        Farroq,
        Quresema,
        Ganesh,
        Harris,
        Imman,
        Jagadish,
        Kevin,
        Lucy,
        Manoj,
        Nathan,
        Oram,
        Pawan,
        Remy,
        San,
        Tanu,
        Urmilla,
        Vidya,
        Watson,
        Xabi,
        Yamini,
        Zaheer
    );
    font = "Marker Felt Thin ";
} Dictionary Values

Comment: while i print i am getting string value ,But its not assign to TextFont

Comment: Is `dict != nil`?  Run the debugger...

Comment: can you show the output

Comment: dict != nil, text font  value is assigned but font does not change

Comment: What method are you calling this in?

Comment: Make sure that they’re included in the target

Comment: if you use custom fonts do you take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk) into account?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: save as MarkerFelt-Thin in your Plist

Comment: You are adding it Marker Felt Thin 25.0  with name and Size If you are using name then Store it properly.

Comment: Show the objects and keys of dictionary

Comment: even i tried storing only name itself;

Comment: Have you Added the Font in Info Plist Of App ? If its Custom Font Not apple Default Font

Comment: No i have added it in the extra  plist file

Comment: Check it You have to add it anyhow then and only then the Font is accessible For Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: Show the contents of the `.plist` file.

Comment: Everyone here is ready to answer your question.If you cooperate with what they ask,it will be nice.

Comment: added plist data screen

Comment: No, not Xcode's view of it; the actual file contents.

Comment: you meant source code of Plist

Comment: AnbuKarthick,Me and Droppy are asking show the vlaues of dictionary.

Comment: dictionary value s

Comment: Does below answer work out?

Comment: Nope guys i dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary key is `font` and not `Font`.  Keys are case-sensitive.

Use:

```
 cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:dict[@"font"] size:15];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the line

```
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[[dict objectForKey:@"Font"]size:15]];
```

It might be like this :

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[dict objectForKey:@"Font"] size:15]];
```

Comment: Good Observation that one extra ] is in question.

Comment: It must be a typo in the question, else you'd get an *unrecognized selector exception*.