# Cannot change size of custom Font

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Hi I am using below code to use custom font style for label text. I've installed it and work fine but the problem is that the size of text does not change. I've tried more times with different sizes. I don't know what should do

```
self.saveButton_label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Saved", nil);
self.saveButton_label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro" size: 13.0];
```

Comment: please try this to see if the font is loaded http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798002/setting-size-to-custom-ios-font-doesnt-work

Comment: You can try: `[self.saveButton_label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue LT Pro" size: 13.0]];`

Comment: Put a breakpoint just after this code and read `(po self.saveButton_label.font)` the value of the font.

Comment: I think the font is not loading properly, you may think you are seeing the correct font, but you might simply be seeing the default Helvetica Neue. Try creating the font on a separate line and logging that result out, I believe you will see that it is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue lies with one of the steps you need to take when adding a custom font to your project, you probably are not noticing the difference because Helvetica Neue is also the default font, which I believe is used if you were to assign nil to UILabel as the font.

I suggest following [this guide](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/), I've used it as a checklist myself when using custom fonts and it has worked, especially take not of the naming, the name you have to use in code might not be the one you see in FontBook or when using Preview on the font.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, In your code you are missing "-" with font name.

```
    self.saveButton_label.text = @"Saved";

     [self.saveButton_label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-LT-Pro size:13.0f]];
```

also you can use below fonts.

```
    HelveticaNeueLTPro-MdCn
    HelveticaNeueLTPro-BdCn
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: No its correct I've seen but the problems is only in size.

Comment: Thank you @Ram S: You were right My font name was wrong.