# fontWithName returns nil for custom fonts after updating to Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts

After updating to Xcode 5.1.1, `fontWithName` for custom fonts always return nil, which caused crash when setting attributes for atributedString.

I ensured my custom font is in the result of `[UIFont familyNames]` and `fontNamesForFamilyName`.

`fontWithName` works fine if I pass in system font name eg. `Helvetica`.

If there's any one encountered the same problem? Then how to solve it? Is it a bug in Xcode?

Comment: check the step 4 in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798002/setting-size-to-custom-ios-font-doesnt-work/13800169#13800169

Comment: @arthan.v thanks but I don't think it's the cause. BTW the code works fine until updating to Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing...everything working perfectly (and has been for months with this project)...updated Xcode to 5.1.1 and now custom fonts are failing.  I confirmed that the fonts were in the bundle and in the fonts array at runtime...just won't do the fontWithName.

Comment: Have you made sure that your fonts are in the target membership?
http://puu.sh/8819G/ec00eb063b.png

Comment: @MichaelKing pretty sure, and I can find the font files in the final `.app` package

Comment: I reverted back to Xcode 5.1 and my custom fonts are working fine.  It's definitely something that has changed in Xcode 5.1.1...

Comment: @DarrenEhlers I removed all the fonts and rows in `info.plist`, and then add the fonts again, it seems back to normal.

Comment: Hmmm...tried removing them and re-adding them, still no change.  I can literally exit Xcode 5.1.1, run Xcode 5.1 and it works perfectly.  Exit project and switch back, and the fonts don't load.  Nothing else changes (confirmed by Git)

Comment: @DarrenEhlers Have you tried creating a new project and add custom fonts in 5.1.1? I firstly created a new project and it works, so I tried re-adding and succeeded. BTW, do you use something like MoarFonts? Once I thought it's related to MoarFonts.

Comment: You appear to be correct, it is related to MoarFonts.  Looks like the problem is resolved (at least in my case) and I posted an answer below.

Comment: Never used MoarFonts in my life but experiencing the same difficulties after upgrading to 5.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem (at least with my install).

I use a program called moarfonts (http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/).

SOMETHING changed between Xcode 5.1 and Xcode 5.1.1, my guess is that it's related to permissions inside the Xcode.app package.

But, anyway, by following the steps from Solution #2 of the MoarFonts troubleshooting  (http://pitaya.ch/moarfonts/#troubleshooting), the problem was resolved and it's working fine now:

```
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
/usr/local/bin/moarfonts reset
```

YAY!  Back to work...

Comment: Great. In fact, my solution is almost the same, I also reset the moarfonts and then re-added fonts, although I don't know which step did the trick. BTW, I've heard that Xcode 5.1 supports custom fonts in xib, but without moarfonts I cannot see any custom font.